# Integrating Netflix Zuul in Web Application

Tags: cors, netflix-zuul

I have an existing web application using servlets and `web.xml`. Is it possible to integrate Zuul into it.

Requirement : The web app is supposed to call another host via AJAX, which gives CORS issue.